# how to make a mysql query with a php variable?

Tags: php, mysql

Can you please guide me? I have been struggling with this for hours now.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<?php
include ("connect.php");

// Retrieve data from Query String

  if( $_REQUEST["ano"] || $_REQUEST["km"] || $_REQUEST["cat"])

//print your car is model xxxx

  echo "tu coche es un ". $_REQUEST["cat"] . ".";

 //start connection to mysql db
 $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

 //mysql query to get average price of select model of car

$query = 'SELECT AVG(price) FROM `fl_listings` WHERE `tmp_catkey` = `'.$_REQUEST["cat"].'`';

$qry_result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qry_result))
{

      echo "<br> El rango de precios de venta es de: ".$row['AVG(price)'];

}
$promedio = $row['AVG(price)'];

?>
</html>
```

I have been changing the quotes to see if it works. I have not been able to get the result. Best I got was the echoed string without the `$row['AVG(price)']`

and in another attempt I got this warning:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Comment: your query failed. Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code. Pretty obvious though.

Comment: Not to mention your query is open to SQL injection. You should be using prepared statements with bound parameters to prevent this. Never put user input directly into your queries.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Not gonna vote to close?

Comment: @Mike Riggs got it ;-)

Comment: Thanks. I see the sql injection risk and will fix that. Also, I noticed the column values are in the format have text in the numbers like '44350|dollar'. The fix would be to get the values, then strip that '|dollar' text and then get the average from the array. any guidance towards doing this?